# How to execute a command from cnoremap?

Tags: vim

I want to map `<M-o>` to quickly look up buflist from command-mode.

Here's an example normal-mode mapping:

```
nnoremap <M-o> :ls<CR>
```

Here's an attempt to do the same for command mode using `execute()`:

```
cnoremap <M-o> <C-r>=execute(':ls')<CR>
```

This however simply appends whitespace-separated `:ls` results to the command line, with no side effect of the `:ls` table actually showing.

Is there a way to execute a command without leaving command-mode?

Update:

Closest I've come to cracking this using Vimscript is the following:

```
function! RunCmdFromCmdline(cmd)
    let l:cmd_line = getcmdline()
    echo execute(a:cmd)
    return l:cmd_line
endfunction

cnoremap <M-o> <C-\>eRunCmdFromCmdline(':ls')<CR>
```

The `echo` makes it so the results of `a:cmd` do pop on the screen, however in invisible font. I tried playing with `:redraw <bar>` in different combinations with no success.

Exiting from the command mode from within a `<C-r>=` or `<C-\>e` prompt does not seem possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. It uses global variables, but arguably this is an acceptable use for them, since there's only a single command-line you can be in at a time.

```
function! SaveCmdline()
  let g:save_cmdline = getcmdline()
  let g:save_cmdpos = getcmdpos()
  return ''
endfunction

function! RestoreCmdline()
  call setcmdpos(g:save_cmdpos)
  return g:save_cmdline
endfunction

cnoremap <M-o> <C-\>eSaveCmdline()<CR>ls<CR>:<C-\>eRestoreCmdline()<CR>
```

This works with whatever quotes or unfinished syntax you have in your command-line, restores the full command-line *and* the cursor to the position it was before running the command, doesn't mess with any registers (only touches the two global variables) and doesn't mess with command-line history either (see `q:` command for history.)

It does have one tiny bug, in that `cnoremap` actually also works when you're typing a search expression (after `/` or `?`) among a few other sub-modes (see `getcmdtype()` for a list of those.) If you use the mapping there, it will search for "ls" and then restore your search term as an Ex command, oops...

You can probably use `getcmdtype()` to detect that and possibly only perform the actions while you're typing an Ex command and not in the other modes.

**UPDATE:** This fixes the last part, only executing the command while in the Ex command-line, not in search or other context. It also makes the interjected command parameterizable.

```
function! CmdlineExecute(cmd)
  if getcmdtype() != ':'
    return ''
  endif
  return "\<C-\>eSaveCmdline()\r".a:cmd.
    \ "\r:\<C-\>eRestoreCmdline()\r"
endfunction

cnoremap <expr> <M-o> CmdlineExecute('ls')
```

(Note this still needs the definition of the two functions above.)

Comment: Glorious! The use of an `<expr>` mapping is particularly ingenious

Answer (score 3):

You can save the contents of the current command line in a register, then run `ls`  and paste the contents of the register:

```
cnoremap <esc>o <home>let @x="<end>"<cr>:ls<cr>:<c-r>x
```

So if command line looks like this:

```
:echo 'some'
```

type `<M-o>` to get:

```
:ls
  1 %a + "filename"          line 1
:echo 'some'
```

Comment: Great and working! I'm trying to reproduce this in a function, so that we don't overwrite any registers.

Comment: Another reason would be of course having any quotes within the command line prior to this :)